# How to make all possible combinations out of letters, but not all of the letters need to be used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools, iterable

I'm making a project in Python, and it involves a function that returns all possible combinations out of letters given as a parameter, but not all of the letters have to be used.
This is my current function:

```
from itertools import product
def algorithm(letters):
    possible = [''.join(combination) for combination in product(letters, repeat=len(letters))]
    return possible
print(algorithm(['a','b','c','d','e']))
```

But it returns only the combinations that have all the letters given in them. It doesn't return combinations like:

```
abc
cba
de
ad
```

etc.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: beacuse you're telling it to repeat by the length of the letters list (i.e. 5) so it'll only get you 5 letters combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import itertools

def generate(vals):
    return ("".join(x) for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(vals,i+1) for i in range(0,len(vals))))

print(list(generate("".join(['a','b','c','d','e']))))
```

This will generate any combination starting from length 1 till 5

Comment: This doesn't allow repetition of letters.

Answer (score 1):

With the least possible changes to your code, the below should work:

```
def algorithm(letters):
    allPoss = list()
    for i in range(1, len(letters)+1):
        possible = [''.join(combination) for combination in product(letters, repeat= i)]
        allPoss.append(possible)
    return allPoss
print(algorithm(['a','b','c','d','e']))
```